# Target specific functions in node server using URL parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building this app where a user can run a function wrapper inside setInterval. I added the user to the api path but I am still getting random results, the script do not clear the interval as I expect, it works only with a single route/user/parameter, can please someone assist with that?

You can run the code below by visiting

> http://localhost:1403/api/v1/user1/random.com?running=true&user=user1&url=random.com

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 1403

app.get('/api/v1/:user/:url', (request, response) => {
    var user = request.query.user;
    var url = request.query.url;

    if (request.query.running === 'false') {
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log("Thread stopped for "
            + user + ' - url : ' + url);
    } else {
        console.log("Thread started for "
            + user + ' - url : ' + url);
        timer = setInterval(
            function apiCall() {
                console.log("api called - thread running for "
                    + user + ' - url : ' + url);
            }, 2000);
    }
    response.sendStatus(200);
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App running on port ${port}!`))
```

My initial goal was to stop the right function by sending the same parameters used to start it and then set `running=false`. It doesn't seems to work because something is missing in this logic. Let me know if I correctly explained the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding of your problem is correct, you are using single `timer` variable (which is accidental global variable as it is not declared). This is will get overridden with latest `intervalId`.

Thats why it is working correct when single request is in progress.

Try to add your `intervalIds` into objects like

```
//at the top
let timers = {};

//in route - to add interval execution
timers[user] = setInterval(...);

//in route - to clear the timer
clearInterval(timers[user]);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but it only works with a single url params, at the moment that's all I am looking for, thanks so much